# best way to switch between secure and unsecure connection without bugging the user

Tags: html, security

The problem I am trying to tackle is simple.  I have two pages - the first is a registration page, I take in a few fields from the user, once they submit it takes them to another page that processes the data, stores it to a database, and if successful, gives a confirmation message.  Here is my issue - the data from the user is sensitive - as in, I'm using an https connection to ensure no eavesdropping.  After that is sent to the database, I'd like on the confirmation page to do some nifty things like Google Maps navigation (this is for a time reservation application).  The problem is by using the Google Maps api, I'd be linking to items through a unsecure source, which in turn prompts the user with a nasty warning message.  I've browsed around, Google has an alternative to enterprise clients, but it costs $10,000 a year.  What I am hoping is to find a workaround - use a secure connection to take in the data, and after it is processed, bring them to a page that isn't secure and allows me to utilize the Google Maps API.  If any of you have a Netflix account you can see exactly what I would like to do when you sign-in, it is a secure page, which then takes you to your account / queue, on an unsecure page.  Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP without annoying error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651772/how-to-redirect-from-https-to-http-without-annoying-error-messages)

Comment: @Art that other question is rather frozen in historical time, and doesn't provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is time to consider retiring support for IE6?

Answer (score 1):

I generally advise never to skip security features, because they are there for a reason, but i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651772/how-to-redirect-from-https-to-http-without-annoying-error-messages) for you to check out.

Comment: Just to update - I am by no means attempting to SKIP security features - I want to have the secure login page, which then directs them to a unsecure page afterwards.  The question is, how to automatically transition between the two without raising warning prompts.  Before posting this question I did stumble upon the link you gave me, however since around 15% of our current users still use IE6 (eek) simply blacklisting that as a browser isn't an option.  Any other suggestions?